# Error while uploading to App store using Application loader

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

We are trying to upload an updated version of the app to the store. The upload takes a long time and finally when its done, we receive the following WARNINGS.

> ... Checksum validation failed.
>
> ... Checksum validation failed.
>
> Transporter was unable to update one or more software components. Please try again later.

The upload is anyway received by the Apple server and the status says "Waiting for review".

Comment: Sounds like there may be a bad Internet connection involved. I'd try submitting the app using a different Internet connection in a different building. If it works there, try calling your ISP.

Comment: having the same issue. can't find the reason. please help

Comment: I have the same problem.My ipa is 1.9 G.

Answer (score 3):

[image: I have got this error while uploading my app to appstore]

Upload has received and app is also approved.So i think there is no much problem with this.

Answer (score 1):

I've ran into the same issue when I tried using the internet connection from my company, either using Application Loader, or Organizer.
In fact, the problem came from my company's firewall which was blocking some ports.
As it is written in Apple support, you may correct this problem by allowing access to the ports indicated in this file : [https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/UsingApplicationLoader.pdf](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1629) from page 6 to 8

Comment: I face the issue now while uploading binary for my new app, the binary is uploaded and its status shows "Waiting For Review". Did you app get approval from Apple after such issue?

Comment: @Saty In fact, the "Waiting for Review" step is a classic one in the submission process. The problem you encountered is just a network one. It does not mean your app will be approved by Apple or not.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can ignore the warning. People who had that warning have had their apps approved by Apple. According to https://forums.adobe.com/message/5949439 it most probably has to do with version number. Here's a quote

> Ignore it. Apple is just letting you know that the version number in
>   the app isn't the same as the version number in iTunes Connect. The
>   iTunes Connect version is what's displayed in iTunes/App Store.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to remove these warnings by clean and Archive but could not. Finally I increase the "Bundle versions string, short" in the project's info.plist file and re-uploaded and successfully uploaded the app without warnings.

Answer (score 0):

1. chec and note  the version number in from ur binary details in itunes
2. delete the updated binary from itunes
3. setup for a new binary to upload
4. clean the project
5. make the bundle name and version name same on ur project(the same on u noted from ur binary details before deleting)
6. Rebuild
7. Archive
8. Validate
9. Distribute