# uploading to App store using Application loader then get error?

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect

We are trying to upload an updated version of the app to the store. The upload takes a long time and finally when its done, we receive the following WARNINGS.

> ... checksum validation failed.
>
> ... checksum validation failed.
>
> Transporter was unable to update one or more software components. Please try again later.

The upload is anyway received by the Apple server and the status says "Waiting for review".!

[image]

Comment: try this https://devforums.apple.com/message/282868#282868

Comment: Did you find any solution to your question? I am also having the same issue. Please help.

Comment: similar hope it helps

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18940640/checksum-validation-failed-when-submitting-with-xcode-5

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error while uploading to App store using Application loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16487953/error-while-uploading-to-app-store-using-application-loader)

Answer (score 1):

Try to reject and resend your binary , it worked for me.