# Checksum Validation Failed when submitting with Xcode 5

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5

I was submitting an app to the iOS App Store a few days ago, and got this message from Xcode. Before I had time to resubmit it, Apple has already started reviewing my app. Is this something I need to worry about?

[image]

Edit: The app was accepted a few days later.

Comment: Has your app been approved with this warning? I just got the same message from Organizer.

Comment: It is now approved. I've installed the update on my phone and looks ok. I still wonder what it was though.

Comment: also got the same error right now with xcode 5. probably a bug.

Comment: I am having the same problem and I tried the solution below but unfortunately it didn't help. Based on your comments above, do you think I should not worry about the error and wait for my app to be reviewed? Is it possible that it gets approved but when people installs it then it crashes on their devices? I am also using Xcode 5 and I tried 2 times to upload it and got the same error.

Comment: @antf I can not suggest further info other than what is written here. Maybe you should contact Apple for this matter. If your app is very critical then you might actually want to solve this issue before releasing it.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I had the same problem and Google led me here. From my understanding a checksum is used to ensure that the file Apple received is identical to the file you (thought you) uploaded to them.

I decided to delete my upload and try again. This worked and I didn't get the error message again. Here's what I actually did:

In iTunes Connect:

- Manage Your Apps > [your app] > View Details of the New Version.
- In the links near the top the right click on Binary Details then, on the next page, Reject This Binary. It says you'll have to prepare another upload but it's just another button to press.
- Back on the View Details page just click 'ready for upload' in the top right. It might say something slightly different but I don't want to delete by upload to double check :P
- You're now ready to upload a new binary.

In xcode:

- Go to Window > Organizer > Archives and delete the archive you previously uploaded.
- In the main window of xcode press cmd-option-shift-k to clean your build folder.
- Make a new archive and upload it like you did before. Fingers crossed all goes well.

Comment: You are correct, technically checksum is used to make ensure both files are the same. The question is, should Apple still accept submissions that fails the checksum? In my case it got in review within 24 hours and approved in about 4 days. So the App Store review team might see the flag that it failed the checksum, but they still do the review anyway.

Comment: I wonder how the checksum failed with us. when would that happen! application loader must make sure that don't happen! I think that something is buggy there?

Comment: All I had to do was follow the first few steps and remove the binary from itunes connect. I uploaded the same binary again and it uploaded without the warning.