# error while submit - executable must include support for armv6

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, armv7, armv6, application-loader

When Validating the Archive, I get the following error:

```
   ERROR ITMS-9000: "This bundle is invalid. When supporting iPhone, the executable must        include support for the armv6 architecture, unless the UIRequireDeviceCapabilities include the 'armv7' capability." at SoftwareAssets/SoftwareAsset (MZItmspSoftwareAssetPackage)
```

I tried with armv6 and armv7 architracture but got the same result.
I want to submit the universal application and using the xcode 5.

I looked in google and found that few other people also has the same issue but one has reported any answer to those question. If any one have any idea about it please share it.

Comment: what you set as your deployment target?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ARMv8 / ARM64 = iPhone 5s
ARMv7s = iPhone 5, iPhone 5c, iPad 4
ARMv7  = iPhone 3GS, iPhone 4, iPhone 4S, iPod 3G/4G/5G, iPad, iPad 2, iPad 3, iPad Mini  
ARMv6  = iPhone, iPhone 3G, iPod 1G/2G
```

iOS 4.3+ requires ARMv7. If your Deployment Target is 4.3

Comment: thanks for your answer. It did worked but it shows some warning. warning is like 1. Checksum validation failed 2. Transporter was unable to update one or more software components. Please try again later.  do you have any idea about it.

Comment: @Satish: 1. sche your internet connection speed may be , or check this SO answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/19173999/1597744