# iOS App Submitted with Validation Warning, but App Status saying Waiting for Review

Tags: ios, app-store

After a whole day search didn't succeed to figure out my problem.

Actually I don't even know is it a problem or not? I'm distributing my first app to app store. So please let me know what should I do now?

[image]

I am curious if this is going wrong then what this App Status saying.

[image]

I also received email from iTunes store team with message :
your app status changed to Waiting for review.

What should i do now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't worry about it. The app has been successfully submitted for review. You'll need to wait it out until you get a feed back from Apple.

Comment: You might be using some 3rd party library which isn't compliant with Apple's rules. For example: there used to be a problem with Facebook's variable by the name 'id' as 'id' in Obj-C typecasts to void.

Comment: You need to wait until a reviewer reviews your app. Will take time. Around 2 weeks atleast.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do anything. Just wait for your binary get accepted/rejected. Otherwise check with your warning, if it's an severe warning, go to itunes and delete your binary & update new one after fix that warning case.

Comment: Just search in google with warning text. like that in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18940640/checksum-validation-failed-when-submitting-with-xcode-5. You will get idea. see this too http://www.mobinett.com/2013/09/20/ios-7-app-validation-warnings-usage-of-non-public-selectors/